# Validate Percentage Field

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi I use the below code to validate a Percentage Field.
The field can accept 2 digits before decimal and 1 digit after decimal.
Values Valid are:
89, 99.9, 1.9,100. 
My code is allowing till 99.9 and not 100. How to change the code to let the user enter 100 also?

```
        function run(el, evt, DivID) {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          var number = el.value.split('.');
          var val = el.value; 
             var caratPos = getItemSelStart (el);
             var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");

             if(number.length>1 && charCode == 46){
                  return false;
              }
             // Added these checks to input 100 also.
             **if ( val == 10 && (val.length > 1 && val.length < 3) && charCode == 48 ) {
                return true;
              }

              if (dotPos == -1 && (val.length > 2) && String.fromCharCode(charCode) == '.') {
                return false;
              }**

             if(dotPos == -1 && val.length > 1 && String.fromCharCode(charCode)!='.' ) {
                 return false;
             }

             if(caratPos > dotPos && (dotPos > -1 ) && number[1].length > 0 ) {
                 return false;
             } 
             if(caratPos == dotPos && dotPos > 1 && number[1].length > 0) {
                 return false;
             }                                           
             return true;  
      }

      function getItemSelStart(o) {
          if (o.createTextRange) {
              var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
              r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length);
              if (r.text == '') return o.value.length;
              return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text);
          } else return o.selectionStart;
      }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to allow 3 digits before the decimal point? I know this allows 999 also but you can check in your `val.length > 1` if the input is 100 and return true instead of false

Comment: That functions refers to some variables that aren't defined in the function - where do they get their values? Please [edit] your question to show all of the relevant code.

Comment: I want to allow only 100 in 3 digit before decimal.

Comment: Added the other variables also. DivId is the Id of the field.

Comment: @KRONWALLED I tried that, but it is not working.

Comment: Could you get all your code, put it in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something like that? It will be faster: I promise ;)

Comment: @KRONWALLED I was trying in JSFiddle. It is really easy and helpful. Can you please tell me how to check if the input is equal to 100 ? I am trying if(val > 100) , but it is not working. Can you please help?

Comment: Thanks for your help @KRONWALLED. I added the above 2 checks and solved the issue. Thanks for introducing JSFiddle.

Comment: Nice that it worked for you. Next time just add the fiddle link in your question so others can reproduce your problem too :)